# How should one use the home tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Going through the [home tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home), it seems there are three primary uses:

1. The home folder,
2. computers that you leave at home, and
3. home networking

Which one should be used, if at all?

Comment: the third is [tag:home-networking] which peopleoften write as  [tag:home]+[tag:networking]

Comment: Thanks, **Updated**.

Answer (score 4):

If a tag is ambiguous and it's not possible to correct that in the excerpt, it should be burninated.

To fit the uses:

1. Should be retagged to [home-folder](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-folder) or to another tag that already fits that purpose.
2. I don't see a point in this, the location context is almost always irrelevant to the actual problem.
3. Should be retagged to [home-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-networking).

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]